# gradle: disable output explicitly leads to verbose output

Tags: java, testing, junit, gradle

I use gradle as build tool for a spring boot application and there I am confronted with some strange behavior. Gradle shows more logging-information on explicitly turn test-outputs off as if I do not specify anything at all.

This is quite strange, because a explicit disable-statement should be at least as expressive as no configuration, or shouldn't it?

Example:
If I add the following lines to my *build.gradle*, I get a by far more verbose logging output on running `gradle test`:

```
test{
    testLogging {
        showStackTraces = false
        showStandardStreams = false
        showExceptions = false
        showCauses = false
        events "failed"
        exceptionFormat "short"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I changed it to `events = []` as @Peter_Niederwieser suggested. Now nearly all messages disappear, except the following one. Has somebody or other an idea how I can suppress them all? I only want to show the result `34 tests completed`and maybe a link to the report.

```
:backend:test
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.2.201302030002/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.2.201302030002.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.6.2.201302030002/org.jacoco.build-0.6.2.201302030002.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.2.201302030002/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.2.201302030002.jar
objc[1360]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
08:50:37.135 [Thread-7] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@228186d4: startup date [Sat Dec 06 08:50:35 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
08:50:37.135 [Thread-6] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4d18a206: startup date [Sat Dec 06 08:50:35 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
08:50:37.135 [Thread-5] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5221dfe5: startup date [Sat Dec 06 08:50:35 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
08:50:37.135 [Thread-8] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@5a5fbef7: startup date [Sat Dec 06 08:50:36 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
08:50:37.166 [Thread-7] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
08:50:37.166 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
08:50:37.167 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
08:50:37.167 [Thread-8] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
08:50:37.167 [Thread-7] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@65bad9fe: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,testConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
08:50:37.168 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@c355f75: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,testConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
08:50:37.168 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6dd79791: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,testConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
08:50:37.168 [Thread-8] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@75a5ec9: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.co                                                                                                                                                                             ntext.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,testConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
08:50:37.175 [Thread-7] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'testConfig'
08:50:37.175 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'testConfig'
08:50:37.176 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'testConfig'
08:50:37.176 [Thread-8] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'testConfig'

34 tests completed, 9 failed
:backend:test FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is `events = []`. The code above sets `events "failed"`, which will result in more verbose logging (each failed test will be logged individually).

Comment: Hi, thanks! This really helped a lot, but there is still some log output left. I updated my question, would you have a suggestion?

Comment: Not sure why you would still see this, but try to place a logging configuration file (for your app's logging framework of choice) into `src/test/resources` that turns off all logging. You can also try if upgrading to the latest Gradle version makes a difference.

Comment: Application Logging is set to DEBUG and I want to keep this. I only want to disable the output on the test-task.

Comment: Perhaps application logging is configured to output to standard out?

Comment: where can I check this? I use the standard spring boot configuration and my application.properties does not contain any logging specific settings at all.